# UITapGestureRecognizer not working with UIImageView Custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

UITapGestureRecognizer is not working with my UIImageView Class on my UIViewController.

```
HousePictureView *pictureHouse = [[HousePictureView alloc] init:[dictionary objectForKey:@"photo_url"]];
UITapGestureRecognizer *picturestap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showpictures)];
picturestap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[pictureHouse addGestureRecognizer:picturestap];
[parentScroll addSubview:pictureHouse];
```

HousePictureView.m

```
@interface HousePictureView() {
    CGFloat screenwidth;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *pictureView;

@end

@implementation HousePictureView


-(id)init:(NSString*)url
{
    screenwidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; // Width of this screen
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _pictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenwidth,300)];
        [_pictureView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[Functions resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nophoto"] newSize:CGSizeMake(screenwidth,300)]];
        _pictureView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self addSubview:_pictureView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

HousePictureView.h

```
@interface HousePictureView : UIImageView

- (id)init:(NSString*)url;

@end
```

Why does it not possible to have an event while userInteractionEnabled form views  parents are activated?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Missing `self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` in `init`?

Comment: @Larme userInteractionEnabled is YES by default.

Comment: Not on `UIImageView`, or that's new.

Comment: @Larme is correct: right in the [UIImageView reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview), under *Responding to Touch Events*, it specifies that `userInteractionEnabled` is set to ignore user interaction by default.

Comment: Why? userInteractionEnabled is set to YES on this function.

Answer (score 0):

mmmhhh you have created an UIImageView custom class with a property UIImageView added like a subview. Why?
Just use "self".

It does not work because you're adding a tap gesture on a UIImageView that is under another.

Comment: But juste use "self" is not working. I don't understand, without UIImageView is working. :/  What to do for use touch in custom class?

Comment: With self it's not working? Why? What did you do in that case?